# How to set var something = 0 when input box is empty in javascripts

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create an if else statements in javascripts to check if the input boxes are empty then var something = 0 else var something = 70 but the problem is when it's empty it's still taking var something = 70 instead of 0 here is my if else statements:-

```
if(parseFloat(document.getElementById('EL1l1a').value) && parseFloat(document.getElementById('EL1cl1a').value) == "") {
    var s = 0;
} else {
    var s = 70;
}
if(parseFloat(document.getElementById('EL1l1b').value) && parseFloat(document.getElementById('EL1cl1b').value) == "") {
    var t = 0;
} else {
    var t = 70;
}
if(parseFloat(document.getElementById('EL1l2a').value) && parseFloat(document.getElementById('EL1cl2a').value) == "") {
    var u = 0;
} else {
    var u = 70;
}
if(parseFloat(document.getElementById('EL1l2b').value) && parseFloat(document.getElementById('EL1cl2b').value) == "") {
    var v = 0;
} else {
    var v = 70;
}
if(parseFloat(document.getElementById('EL1l3a').value) && parseFloat(document.getElementById('EL1cl3a').value) == "") {
    var w = 0;
} else {
    var w = 70;
}
if(parseFloat(document.getElementById('EL1l3b').value) && parseFloat(document.getElementById('EL1cl3b').value) == "") {
    var x = 0;
} else {
    var x = 70;
}
if(parseFloat(document.getElementById('EL1l4a').value) && parseFloat(document.getElementById('EL1cl4a').value) == "") {
    var y = 0;
} else {
    var y = 70;
}
if(parseFloat(document.getElementById('EL1l4b').value) && parseFloat(document.getElementById('EL1cl4b').value) == "") {
    var z = 0;
} else {
    var z = 70;
}
var EL1total2 = s + t + u + v + w + x + y + z
```

Edit:- here is a demo of what am trying to achieve 
http://jsfiddle.net/tj420pbj/

just to explain more in details I want to set some variables depending on the input box if it's empty then the variable should be 0 if there is some value in the input box then the variable should be 0 so I can take that variable and use it in another process to find the overall gpa the demo will show you what am trying to achieve

Note:- the level 3 and 4 still under development so ignore it

Comment: In this specific case, you could easily use a nice shorthand: `var a = document.getElementById('myinput').value || 70` (which simply says, if the first thing is falsy, use the second one!)

Comment: `parseFloat("")` returns `NaN`, which is `false`. The condition is always `false` when the fields are empty.

Comment: Can include `html` at Question ?

Comment: Ok I've just added right now you can check it when you are free @guest271314

Comment: _"if it's empty then the variable should be 0 if there is some value in the input box then the variable should be 0 "_ ? If some value should variable be set to `70` , or value of input  ?

Comment: yeah if there is some value in the input box then the variable should be set to 70 and if there is nothing entered then it should be set to 0 what am trying to say no mater what is the value of the input box is I want the variable should be set to 70 else if there is no value in the input box then the variable should be set to 0 @guest271314

Comment: which post ? edit:- I saw it just wait @guest271314

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if there is some value in the input box then the variable should be
>   set to 70 and if there is nothing entered then it should be set to 0

If interpret Question , expected logic correctly , could use `Array.prototype.map()` , `Array.prototype.reduce()`

```js
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");
var button = document.querySelector("button");
button.onclick = function() {
  var res = [].map.call(inputs, function(a, index) {
    return Number(a.value) > 0 ? 70 : 0
  }).reduce(function(a, b) {
    return Number(a) + Number(b)
  })
  console.log(res)
}
```

```html
<input type="number" step="0.01" />
<input type="number" step="0.01" />
<input type="number" step="0.01" />
<input type="number" step="0.01" />
<input type="number" step="0.01" /><br />
<button>click</button>
```

---

using jQuery . To select only elements having "semester" value , tru selector `$(".ui-listview li:eq(1) input[name*='cl']")`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#EL1cal1").click(function () {
        var res = $(".ui-listview li:eq(1) input[name*='cl']")
            .map(function (i, el) {
                console.log(el)
            return Number(el.value) > 0 ? 70 : 0
        }).get().reduce(function (a, b) {
            return Number(a) + Number(b)
        })
        console.log(res)
    })
})
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tj420pbj/2/

Comment: still not getting it how it works by the way I'm new in javascript @guest271314

Comment: @AlAmri At click of `button , at `.map()` if input value is greater than `0` ,  return  `70` , else return `0` ; at `.reduce()` add each input values returned from `.map()` , return sum `res`

Comment: but this will check the values of all inputs in the page that includes the GPA of each semester and the results of GPA calculation of each level am I right? which I don't want to be added @guest271314

Comment: What is selector of input elements that should be checked ?

Comment: the code is working fine but still it's checking for each input box in the page I just want to check for each input box that shows the total credits of semesters @guest271314

Comment: I modified the code and took each id of input that I need and it's working as I want thanks for helping @guest271314

Comment: @AlAmri _"I modified the code and took each id of input that I need and it's workin"_ Updated post using selector `$(".ui-listview li:eq(1) input[name*='cl']")` to select only "semester" input elements

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `parseFloat` on a blank value (ie, when the field is empty), and comparing it to a blank string, this will *never* evaluate true.

In actual fact, you will get `NaN` when you try to parse a blank string.

```js
alert(parseFloat(""))
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because your condition is

```
if(parseFloat(document.getElementById('EL1l1a').value) && parseFloat(document.getElementById('EL1cl1a').value) == ""
```

Which is literally saying if it has a value AND it's blank.  This will never be true...

Comment: `"EL1l1a" !== "EL1cl1a"`

Comment: oh.  I thought they were the same.  Pffft.  Good argument for shorthanding, as was suggested further down.

Comment: I also missed this to start - OP has some *horrible* naming convention for their fields! `1`'s next to lower case `l`'s should be a capital offense in field naming